# How to I resolve the error "This environment variable is too large" in Windows?

Tags: windows, path, windows-10, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable in Windows 10, but it fails with an error:

> This environment variable is too large. This dialog allows setting values up to the 2047 characters.

I'm learning **React-Native** and using **android studio**, I want to include the path to **abd.exe** in my %PATH% environment variable.

I tried to fix this by removing some of the values in the PATH variable, but I still get this same error.

Error Screenshot:

[image: env variable too large error]

I will appreciate this if anyone can assist me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1385854/how-do-i-bypass-restrictions-on-the-length-of-the-path-variable

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend **cleaning** the PATH variable up, removing anything you no longer need. You can also reduce the length by adding new environment variables like

```
x86 = %ProgramFiles(x86)%
x64 = %ProgramFiles%
```

And refer to them by `%x86%`, etc. This also makes the PATH variable more manageable.

Comment: you can even include `C:\\` to optimize a bit further.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that a recent Windows Update changed the allowed length of an environment variable from 4095 to 2047. I hope this is a bug not a feature. I have the same issue, getting error trying to save unmodified PATH environment variable results in "This variable is too large" error.